# in AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) is it better to use eventListener or readyStateChange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I was re-watching a video from WWDC12 on advanced effects with HTML5 and noticed that for the demo they used `req.addEventListener("load",callback,true)` rather than the usual `onreadystatechange`.

What are the differences between the load event and `state=4 status=200` situation?
Is it the same load event being fired or two different ones?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783053/xmlhttprequest-is-always-calling-load-event-listener-even-when-response-has-e. From that answer, my guess is that `load` fires when `readyState==4`. The `load` event only indicates *network* success (i.e., the server was found), not HTTP success (e.g., an HTTP error code may be returned). However, I can't find the spec detailing how and when `load` is fired for an Ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` event only indicates that the request was a *network* success, not necessarily an HTTP success. An Ajax request with always either fire a `load` event or an `error` event, indicating the success or failure of the network transaction (as part of the [Progress Events](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) specification):

- The `error` event fires when the network fetch fails due to the server being down or on an inaccessible domain (i.e., the request is blocked by the same-origin policy).
- Otherwise, `load` fires, regardless of the HTTP code returned.

The `load` or `error` event always fires last, after the last `readstatechange` event has fired, so you can be sure that the `load` or `error` callback is running with `xhr.readyState == 4` and `xhr.status` set to the correct HTTP response code.