# Nothing happens in this javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this java script:

```
document.onreadystateChange = function() {
    if (document.readystate === "complete") {
        var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
        var b0 = menu[0];
        b0.addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location = 'services.html', false;
        });
    }
};
```

the HTML part is:

```
<div class = "menu">
   <p>
      Home
   </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to open services.html but nothing happens... no error being thrown.

What am I doing wrongly here?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, when I removed that strange looking readyStateChange handler that never fires ?

Comment: @ j08691 Sorry but I don't understand your question. it's my very first website I'm trying to learn it by myself.

Comment: it's `onreadystatechange` and `document.readyState`. Javascript is CaSe SeNsItIvE. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktDp3/)

Comment: You're sure you wouldn't be better of with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded), or do you really have to support old IE.

Comment: instead of `document.onreadystatechange = function...` you should use `document.addEventListener('load', function...)` - [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366094/in-ajax-xmlhttprequest-is-it-better-to-use-eventlistener-or-readystatechange)

Comment: Matt Burland & MrCode, you're right about js being case sensitive. Working fine now. Thanks a lot for all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is all lower case, but you have a capital C. JavaScript is case sensitive. Also `readystate` should be `readyState` Change to:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {

    }
};
```

[MDN docs for `onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange).